# Sed - modify single character in first column without touching others

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a list of interfaces that I need to modify the original files  `.` to `:` so I can feed them into an ifconfig script.

It looks basically like this:

```
eth0.1 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0

eth0.2 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

eth0.3 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

Using my basic sed knowledge I can do the following:

```
sed -i 's/\./\:/g' <test_file>
```

which turns all `.` into `:`.

```
eth0:1 192:168:0:1 255:255:255:0
```

Now, if I weren't modifying the original file I know I could `awk '{print $1}'` however I don't know how to do this when using `sed -i`.

I should mention that there are also certain lines that are not subinterfaces such as:

```
eth1 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

Dropping the `g` in `sed` (which I'm sure it's the right direction) unfortunately modifies the first octet for these lines to:

```
eth1 10:10.10.1...
```

Comment: Just drop the `g` flag on the s command.

Comment: William -> Sorry, just added an edit. Some lines aren't subinterfaces, so that modifies those as well. Is there a grep -v function of sed that I can exclude these with?

Comment: Respect the work of others Numpty, you have skipped some good edits. Your post is a mess now again.

Comment: sputnick: I don't mean to offend anyone. Could you be clearer? I'm not sure what I've skipped >.<

Comment: You had edited your post, but in the meantime sudo_O & me had edited that post too. See edit history

Comment: You don't need a grep -v.  To change the first occurence of `.` to `:`, but only on lines that begin 'eth[0-9].', use `sed '/eth[0-9]\./s/./:/'`

Comment: If you posted the input file and the expect output file things would be much easier.. lets not play the game where you get answers then modified the question to say actually my file contains...

Comment: Few issues with that William, but close. Sputnick got it :)
@sudo, being IP's of live production boxes, no, I can't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -i -r 's/^(eth[0-9]+)\./\1:/' file.txt
```

Output :

```
eth0:1 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
eth0:2 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
eth0:3 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
```